# Let the diameter of a subset S of the plane be defined as the maximum of the distance between arbitrary of points of S

Tags: geometry, locus

Let the diameter of a subset S of  the plane be defined as the maximum of the distance between arbitrary of points of S.

Let$$S=\{(x,y):(y-x)\le0,(x+y)\ge0,x^2+y^2\le2\}$$

Then the diameter of S is '2'.

I am unable to gain thaat solution.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you draw a diagram of this region?

Comment: It will be a circle.

Comment: It's a quadrant of a circle.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/PsZvBpH.png

See the intersection of all three colours? That's your graph.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6xmu1r  @Ilham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set $S$ is the part of circle of radius $\sqrt2$ between the bisectrices of the first and fourth quadrants.

[image]

So his diameter is the distance between the points $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ (black points on the circe) : $d=2$.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6xmvg3 @Emilio Novati

Comment: @Rishabh Yeah, so can you find that distance?

Comment: @Ilham.  It will be distance between the points (1,1) and (1,-1). Since the the distance to be found is to be the maximum distance. We will consider the points on the circle with radius 2(the maximum radius possible) ????